Zoom is limiting to 30 results
I am using a civi zoom extension and having an issue where when getting zoom meeting ids from the API there are only 30 results ever returned.
Code in extension
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
      'base_uri' => 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/',
      'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . ($tokenRecord['access_token'] ?? ''),
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
      ],
    ]);

    try {
      $json = (string) $client->$action($url, [GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => $params])->getBody();
      $result = json_decode($json, true);
    }

I have tried adding next page token, page number and pagesize parameters to the $params - but these are all seemingly ignored.
Is the 30 records a new limit enforced by Zoom?
Is there a way to specify more than 30 records other than the $params var above?
I have tried adding vars in an array to $params - but these are all ignored.

https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/Listmeetingsummaries suggests there's a page_size parameter with a default value of 30...
